# Zero or more occurrences of pattern matching in sql stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, stored-procedures

In my stored procedure, I want to set student ID pattern and further based on that pattern I want to retrieve data from table.

Student ID pattern should be like string `STUD-`, followed by 2 to 3 digits.

The pattern should have values from `STUD-11` and `STUD-125`

For example: `STUD-12` and `STUD-123`.

Currently I am using pattern as :

```
SET @stud_ID_like = 'STUD-[1-9][0123456789]'
```

But it accepts `STUD-10` that I don't want.

And how can I get 3 digits after string `STUD-`.

For this if I use `STUD-[1-9][0123456789][0123456789]` pattern then how can I take 2 digit value like `STUD-15`.

Is there '*' wild card character in SQL for pattern matching so that I can use it for zero or more occurrences ? Or any other solution for this ?

My stored procedure is something like this:

```
stored procedure A
    @stud_ID_like varchar(128)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @stud_ID_like = 'STUD-[1-9][0123456789]'

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        SELECT TOP 1 [Student Name]
        FROM [Student_list_table] 
        WHERE [Result] = 'PASS' AND [St_ID] LIKE @stud_ID_like 

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

Comment: Looks like you're referring to regex, but that has nothing to do with the code you show or the question you asked. please explain

Comment: So, "STUD-11", "STUD-15", or "STUD-28" are okay?, Is "STUD-10" a special case that you want to reject?  Would "STUD-20" be okay?  Would "STUD-100" be allowed?

Comment: `STUD-[0-9][0-9][0-9]` would force it to have 3 digits after `STUD-` i believe.  Change to `STUD-[1-9][0-9][0-9]` for `100-999`

Comment: @LDMJoe , Except STUD-1 to STUD-10 , all other Values fromSTUD-11 to STUD-125 is valid values for me. And main thing is how can I check zero or more occurance so that I can use it for 3rd digit

Answer (score 2):

You can build or statements for the matches between `STUD-11` and `STUD-125`

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Student Name]
FROM [Student_list_table] 
WHERE [Result] = 'PASS' 
AND [St_ID] LIKE 'STUD-1[1-9]' 
    OR [St_ID] LIKE 'STUD-[2-9][0-9]'
    OR [St_ID] LIKE 'STUD-1[0-1][0-9]'
    OR [St_ID] LIKE 'STUD-12[0-5]'
```

[**SQL Fiddle Example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/1129)

Might be less trouble to pass in a min id and max id, then convert the value after `STUD-` to an `int` and compare that way.

```
CREATE PROC A (
    @Min INT,
    @Max INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @Min = 11
    SET @Max = 125

    SELECT TOP 1 [Student Name]
    FROM [Student_list_table] 
    WHERE [Result] = 'PASS' 
        AND CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING([St_ID], PATINDEX('%-%', [St_ID]) + 1, LEN([St_ID]))) 
            BETWEEN @Min AND @Max
END
```

Comment: The last line doesn't need the 2 in square brackets - it can be part of the literal, like the 1.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will not use index if any exists on StudentID column:

```
where replace(StudentID, 'STUD-', '') between 11 and 125
```

Comment: `'%STUD-[1-9][0-9]%'` would include `STUD-10` and `STUD-100` and `STUD-10000000000000`  so why would you need the or?

Comment: @user1221684, there where unneeded `%`

Comment: [1-9][0-9]% includes 10 also . Is there '*' wild card concept in sql ?

Comment: @beginner, just change [0-9] to [1-9]. Did you try that?

Comment: i think he wants 11-125.. you just need more ORs.  your latest edit would exclude 20, 30, 40, etc..

Comment: O my God, you have your question in your question and in comments to your question and in comments to answers. Can't you just edit your question and describe exactly what do you want? I think last edit is what you need...

Comment: definitely confusing.. but `'STUD-[1][0-2][0-5]'` excludes 106-109 and 116-119

Answer (score 1):

To meet the criteria as specified, you'd have to do 3 parts.

From the OP comment..

> Except STUD-1 to STUD-10 , all other Values fromSTUD-11 to STUD-125 is
>   valid values for me. And main thing is how can I check zero or more
>   occurance so that I can use it for 3rd digit

```
WHERE
    (
        StudentID LIKE 'STUD-[1-9][0-9]' 
        AND 
        StudentID != 'STUD-10'
    )
    OR
    (
        StudentID LIKE 'STUD-[1-9][0-9][0-9]' 
    )
```

This will cover 11 - 999

You can continue nesting conditions like this if you want to forcibly exclude values >= 126, but it gets ugly.  One of the other proposed answers takes a stab at it, but accidentally excluded all values over 100 that ended with a digit higher than 5.

Comment: my answer is anything 11-125.. not that ugly

Comment: @user1221684 way less ugly than what I was about to type - I was going to allow up to 130 then explicitly exclude 126-130. You get my upvote.